# functional scrollDown button

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I've been trying to make an arrow to make a scrollDown, and I managed to traverse the div 100% height, but doesnt work with the second click.

```
    var n = $(document).height();

$("#arrow").click(function() {
    $(".aside").animate({ scrollTop: n }, 1000);
    $("#arrow").css("bottom",-n);
});
```

Any advice?

Comment: Elaborate on `doesn't work` please

Comment: here is the example
http://jsfiddle.net/yuFk5/250/

i need that after second click the arrow button keeps scrolling